# how to read exif data and decode the image from same io.Reader

Tags: go, exif

I'm writing a go application that uses `gqlgen` for graphQL API.

when a user uploads a file using the api I get it as a type of `graphql.Upload`

```
type Upload struct {
    File        io.Reader
    Filename    string
    Size        int64
    ContentType string
}
```

I want to be able to load the exif data of the image, decode the image and rotate it based on the exif orientation.

I use `github.com/rwcarlsen/goexif/exif` to fetch the exif information and `github.com/disintegration/imaging` for rotation, but I cannot open `graphql.Upload.File` twice. it fails the 2hd time.

```
func updateImage(dir string, id int, imgFile *graphql.Upload) error {
    image := dbimage.GetImagePathNoTemplate(dir, id)
    imageThumbnail := dbimage.GetImageThumbnailPathNoTemplate(dir, id)
    var myImage image2.Image
    var err error
    switch imgFile.ContentType {
    case "image/png":
        if myImage, err = png.Decode(imgFile.File); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        break
    case "image/jpeg":
        if myImage, err = jpeg.Decode(imgFile.File); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        break
    case "image/webp":
        if myImage, err = webpbin.Decode(imgFile.File); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        break

    default:
        return errors.Errorf("unknown image mimetype %v", imgFile.ContentType)
    }
   FAILS HERE:  metaData, err := exif.Decode(imgFile.File)
   ...
}
```

of course if I extract the exif first and then  decode the image, then the image decode fails.

I don't get a full path to the file and I get only one `io.Reader`. what can I do to fetch both exif and decode the image ?

thanks

Comment: Is the `io.Reader` backed by a file? (or more generally is it an `io.Seeker`?). If not then there's no other solution than to simply buffer the data so you can re-read it.

Comment: Cast it to see if it can be an `io.Seeker` so you can roll back. If not you can only make a copy into the memory. However, you may only read a small part that contains the EXIF data of the reader and then use `io.MultiReader` to put the part back to minimize memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys thank you for your comments.

I noticed that I cannot  cast `io.Reader` to `io.Seeker`.
for some reason I thought that `io.Reader` got some sort of rewind method that I missed but this is not the case.

so what I did is read the data to a byte array and created new Reader object whenever I need it:

```
byteArray, err := ioutil.ReadAll(imgFile.File)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

switch imgFile.ContentType {
case "image/png":
    if myImage, err = png.Decode(bytes.NewReader(byteArray)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    break
case "image/jpeg":
    if myImage, err = jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(byteArray)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    break
case "image/webp":
    if myImage, err = webpbin.Decode(bytes.NewReader(byteArray)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    break

default:
    return errors.Errorf("unknown image mimetype %v", imgFile.ContentType)
}
metaData, err := exif.Decode(bytes.NewReader(byteArray))
```